# How to show/hide specific table rows using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, show-hide

I'm displaying some data in a table and for each row I have another one with some details that is hidden by default and I want to make it visible only when the user clicks a link.

HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="listing">
    <?php for(): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#" class="toggle">Toggle</a></td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="details" style="display: none">
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>   
    <?php endfor; ?>
</div>
```

I tried using jQuery like so, but with no results:

```
$('#listing').on('click', '.toggle', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('tr .details').toggle();
});
```

Comment: The HTML you're generating is invalid. A table needs to start and end with  `<table>` and `</table>`

Comment: Why is that? It's only a sample, not the entire code.

Comment: @j08691, as I said, I wrote a simplified version to post it here. It didn't feel like necessary to post the entire code.

Comment: I never asked you to post the entire code. I merely pointed out that what you're generating by the example code you posted results in invalid HTML.

Comment: If not the entire code: based on what do you expect inputs from the community? Just as @j08691 pointed out, the generated HTML is invalid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On each first row element provide it a `data-target` this will be which class to target and `toggle` the show/hide.

So basically on click for `toggle` class we get the `data-target` use that value to find our target and then simply `toggle` the target.

JsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/63ujphmj/

Javascript

```
$(function()
{
    $('.toggle').on('click', function()
  {
    var target = $(this).data('target');
    $('.'+target).toggle();
  });
});
```

Html

```
<div id="listing">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="#" class="toggle" data-target="details-1">Toggle 1</a></td>
      <td><a href="#" class="toggle" data-target="details-2">Toggle 2</a></td>
      <td><a href="#" class="toggle" data-target="details-3">Toggle 3</a></td>
      <td><a href="#" class="toggle" data-target="details-4">Toggle 4</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="details">
      <td class="details-1" style="display: none">Toggle 1 details</td>
      <td class="details-2" style="display: none">Toggle 2 details</td>
      <td class="details-3" style="display: none">Toggle 3 details</td>
      <td class="details-4" style="display: none">Toggle 4 details</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: @Cosmin not a problem

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you fix the invalid HTML and include `<table>` tags, you want to use:

```
$('#listing').on('click', '.toggle', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('tr').next('.details').toggle();
});
```

You need to use `.closest('tr')` to traverse up in the DOM from the button clicked to the parent row, then `.next('.details')` to move to the next row element.